# Nifi : Count the number of rows in flowfile for current run and check if the count is >= count of number of rows in flowfile for previous run

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, data-ingestion

I am new to Nifi and I am looking for some help to implement the below requirement :

Count the number of rows in flowfile for current run and check if the count is >= count of number of rows in flowfile for previous run.

QuerydatabaseTable -> (get the number of records of current and previous flow files ) -> (verify if the condition is true?)

This is what i am looking to achieve.
Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need to store the state, please refer link to start with - https://gist.github.com/ijokarumawak/01c4fd2d9291d3e74ec424a581659ca8

Comment: Thank you @VikramsinhShinde,but can you please elaborate bit more. Lets say in the first run I have count of 100, should i store this 100 in store state?.In the next run the count is 120.Here i need to compare if 120>100,and now if this condition is true ,100 should be updated 120.Meaning to say for the next run 120 will be reference value to check against.

Comment: Please refer section `Stateful Usage` here to get implementation details - 
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html